# Getting 500 Internal server error for Microsoft bot framework directline v3.0 requests

Tags: rest, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am following the exact steps mentioned in the documentation to generate a new token from the directline secret for v3.0 using the REST API.

Hitting the API endpoint with a POST request: https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate

Headers:
Authorization: Bearer SECRET

I obtained the SECRET from my bot page under "Configure directline" section.

Here's a snap:
[image]

I am getting a 500 Internal server error. How do I get around this?

Comment: Try looking at the full response in a proxy like Fiddler, there may be extra information in it.